# Message Queue (mqueue.h), Invalid Argument Error, In C

Tags: c, message-queue, mqueue

I have not been able to create and open a message queue in C.

I tried with various arguments to `mq_open()` function yet nothing has come out of it.

I have checked some similar issues, but have not been able to get a solution.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I am getting a `mq_open: Invalid argument` error.

```
// Create the message queue
mqd_t mq;

// Open the message queue
mq = mq_open(argv[1], O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 0666, NULL);
if (mq == (mqd_t)-1) {
       perror("mq_open");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

I am arbitrarily giving it the name 'a'.

Comment: What name are you giving the queue?

Comment: I am arbitrarily giving it the name 'a'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am arbitrarily giving it the name 'a'.

That is an invalid name for a message queue.  Such names must begin with a leading "/".  This spelled out in the [man page for mq_overview](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html), which is referenced in the man page for mq_open:

> Message queues are created and opened using mq_open(3);  this
> function    returns  a  message queue descriptor (mqd_t), which is
> used to refer to    the open message queue in later calls.  Each
> message queue  is  identi‐    fied by a name of the form /somename;
> that is, a null-terminated string    of up to NAME_MAX (i.e.,  255)
> characters  consisting  of  an  initial    slash,  followed  by one or
> more characters, none of which are slashes.    Two processes can
> operate on the same queue by passing the same name to    mq_open(3).